# Aproximar al siguiente valor entero por mas pequeño que sea el decimal JAVA

Tags: java, math

Necesito dividir una lista dependiendo de la cantidad de registros establecidos.

Si el maximo de registros es de 500000 y la lista tiene 500001 debo generar dos listas, una de 500 mil registros y otra de un solo registro. Ese numero esta configurado por parametro entonces necesito calcular la cantidad de listas que voy a generar.

Necesito aproximar al valor entero siguiente despues de dividir el el numero configurado (500000)

500001/500000 = 1,000002 => 2 -->Resultado.

No logro encontrar una función que me permita calcular el numero entero seguiente por mas pequeño que sea el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorda que una división es solo una sucesión de restas, si queres saber cuantas listas necesitas, solo debes tomar la cantidad de registros como si fuera un acumulador y restar la cantidad máxima mientras el acumulador sea mayor a 0, la cantidad de veces que haces esto lo guardas en un contador y listo.

este seria el codigo:

```
public int calcularCantidadListas(int registros, int cantidadMaxima)
    {
        int contador = 0;
        do{
           contador++;
           registros-=cantidadMaxima;     
       }while(registros > 0);
       
        return contador;
    }
```

lo ejecute con las siguientes cantidades para probar:

```
A a = new A();
       System.out.println("cantidad de listas: "+  a.calcularCantidadListas(5001, 5000));
       System.out.println("cantidad de listas: "+  a.calcularCantidadListas(5000, 5000));
       System.out.println("cantidad de listas: "+  a.calcularCantidadListas(300, 50));
       System.out.println("cantidad de listas: "+  a.calcularCantidadListas(100, 30));
```

y dieron los siguientes resultados:

```
cantidad de listas: 2
cantidad de listas: 1
cantidad de listas: 6
cantidad de listas: 4
```

con esa función calculas la cantidad y despues podes crear la cantidad de listas que necesites.

Answer (score 2):

Te comparto una función que tal ves te puede ayudar. El rango corresponde a los 500K y la lista tiene un registro más. Entonces te queda una lista con 500K y la siguiente de 1. Saludos

```
private static void dividirListas(List<String> lista, int rango) {
    if (lista.size() > 0) {
        if (lista.size() == 1) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(lista.get(0));
            lista.remove(0);
            System.out.println(list.get(0));
        } else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < rango; i++) {
                list.add(lista.get(0));
                lista.remove(0);
            }
            for (String lista1 : list) {
                System.out.println(lista1);
            }
        }
        dividirListas(lista, rango);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java Math ofrece Math.ceil

```
//Ejemplo Ceil. Debes almacenar primero el resultado como double y los numeros a dividir tambien tienen que ser double para que te den una fraccion divisible como muestra a continuacion. 
 double division = 500001D/500000D;
System.out.println(Math.ceil(division)); //Da como resultado: 2.0
```